# Monitor youtube video playback time

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a youtube video in an iframe on a HTML page.
I want to fire some event when the youtube video playback reaches 5 seconds.

I am using `player.getCurrentTime()` method of youtube api.

HTML code:

```
<div><iframe id="frameID" width="640" height="390" frameborder="0" title="YouTube video player" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1"></iframe></div>
```

JS:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('frameID', {
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': stateChange
    }
});
}
var playedFirstTime=0; //to check if the video is played first time
function stateChange(evt) {

         if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && playedFirstTime==0) {
             playedFirstTime=1
        timestampReached(); //if video is played first time then call the method.
    }

};
function timestampReached()
{

   var myVar= setInterval(function(){   
   if(player.getCurrentTime()>5)   //checking the current time after each second
   {
       alert("reached");
       clearInterval(myVar);

   }
},1000);

}

function onPlayerReady(event) {

//    timestampReached();
}
```

Currently I am showing the alert box if video playback reaches 5 seconds.

The above code is working correctly but the problem is, here, I am checking the current time after each second till 5 seconds (or even more if video is paused before 5 seconds). This is increasing the overhead. What I want is, some way which can call a callback method after specified time has elapsed and I don't need to check for the time continuously.

Comment: The YouTube API does not have this capability; while the underlying HTML5 video will emit the "timeupdate" event, it isn't exposed through the player's iframe at all. Your monitoring solution, however, does not have that much overhead, so it's perfectly do-able.

Comment: @jlmcdonald Thanks for the info. Just a quick question- as I am new in javascript, can you plese tell me when I am doing `player.getCurrentTime()`, is it making a call to the server or it is being fulfilled at client side itself ?

Comment: It's all client side; the 'player' object is a wrapper for the iframe that holds the YouTube video, and calling getCurrentTime() asks the iframe's api to report on the last posted time. Note that it only updates the time 6 or 7 times a second, so you wouldn't want to poll any more frequently than that.